# Why the Number of Bits is Different in File and The Binary Representation of the same File?

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, binaryfiles, binary-data

I have written a code (given at the end of the post) which simply converts the bytes of a file (= `byte_obj`) into a binary number `binary_dt`, so I expect the number of bits in `byte_obj` and `binary_dt` to be same, but that is not case, I used a 3 KB text file and got a output of 17 KB file (output = writing the `binary_dt`into text file), why is that?

Note that, the number of byte-object in `byte_obj` of the file is  2117, and the size of `byte_obj` (with an overhead over the actual content, due to structure data) is 2150, so not much difference here..

So, what is wrong can anyone please explain? and what should I do If I want to get same number of bits from `binary_dt` and in `byte_obj` ?

```
import sys

input_file="a.txt";output_file="b.txt"
with open(input_file, "rb") as file: #--> open file in binary read mode
  byte_obj = file.read() #--> read all binary data


print("Number of byte-object in 'byte_obj' = ",len(byte_obj))
print("The size of 'byte_obj' (has an overhead over the actual content, due to structure data) = \n",str(sys.getsizeof( byte_obj))) #Return the size of an object in bytes.


binary_dt=bin(int.from_bytes( byte_obj, byteorder=sys.byteorder))

print("The number of bits in 'binary_dt' on PC= \n",len(binary_dt)) #Return the size of an object in bytes.
print("binary_dt: \n",binary_dt)

text_file = open(output_file, "w")
n = text_file.write(binary_dt)
text_file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you're reading binary and writing ASCII:

```
>>> bin(3)
'0b11'
```

Here are 2 bits converted into 4 bytes.

Comment: I am new, would u plz tell how to both read and write as binary? which function do I need? note that I need a binary string of those bytes, i.e., I need a binary string from that file.

Comment: @MikeSQ you should add to your question the expected and the actual output of your program, along with the input. preferably of the smallest size possible -- don't use 17kb files, start from something small, like 5-6bytes.